# How to move polygon fit to Google satellite in Qgis

Tags: qgis, satellite

I have a huge polygon layer of land areas and houses in a river delta. It does not really align with the images form Google satellite, so I tried moving the polygon layer. When I do so, it can't be loaded.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you checked, if  the coordiante systems of both your data and the google images( is this a wms?) are equal?

Comment: Google uses the coordinate system with the EPSG code 3857, so try transforming your layer into the same coordinate system and they should fit.

Comment: thanks for your idea, i just check coordinate both of them, they do not match, but I adjusted to match CRS of google satellite but still not

Comment: What do you mean "it can't be loaded"? In QGIS you can load a layer, edit it, select all features, move them, then stop editing, save changes, save the layer and then you should be able to start a new project and load it in and have it in the new position. What precisely are you doing and what error message are you getting?

Comment: My layer has a total of 403000 attributes, when I use "move feature" qgis automatically turn off and not load anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I found the standard coordinate system of the layer and brought it closer to google satellite, Thanks Erick for editing my question and everyone[image: **enter image description here**]

***emphasized text***